MbedTls: Does mbedtls_gcm_auth_decrypt output have the same length as input after decryption? Why/Does it need an extra 8 trailing bytes during?
MBedTls AES-GCM-In-Place-Decryption: Does mbedtls_gcm_auth_decrypt output-buffer have the same length as the input-buffer after encryption? Why does it/Does it really need an extra 8 trailing bytes during decryption?
The MbedTls-documentation for "mbedtls_gcm_auth_decrypt" (e.g. for AES GCM decryption) states

"Note: For decryption, the output buffer cannot be the same as input buffer. If the buffers overlap, the output buffer must trail at least 8 Bytes behind the input buffer."

It also states that for the length-parameter:

"length – The length of the ciphertext to decrypt, which is also the length of the decrypted plaintext."

Does this mean that the 8 extra trailing bytes are just needed during the decryption, but not after?
(If they aren't needed this would be useful for in-place en- and decryption, so that the buffer could be used as the same outside the function doing the decryption.)
Also is the 8 Bytes requirement even applicable currently?
(I tried in-place decryption with basically "malloc(plainTextLength)" and passed the allocated and initialized buffer as both input and output, and it worked without any problem/without me ever allocating the 8 trailing bytes?)
Additional info:
-full signature of the function is
"int mbedtls_gcm_auth_decrypt(mbedtls_gcm_context *ctx, size_t length, const unsigned char *iv, size_t iv_len, const unsigned char *add, size_t add_len, const unsigned char *tag, size_t tag_len, const unsigned char *input, unsigned char *output)"
-it doesn't perform the decryption directly and internally calls mbedtls_gcm_crypt_and_tag which calls mbedtls_gcm_starts, mbedtls_gcm_update_ad, mbedtls_gcm_update, mbedtls_gcm_finish
-mbedtls_gcm_auth_decrypt also seems to zeroize the output (so also the input for in-place decryption) if the tag doesn't match using mbedtls_platform_zeroize.

Seems that's a known issue
